# Screen resolution not recongized, drivers not working

Tags: drivers, ati, resolution, screen

For no apparent reason after restarting my laptop the screen resolution which was a native 1920x1080p on my Samsung Syncmaster went down to 1400x1050p. I checked "Displays" in my system settings and found that my monitor was no longer recognized and its stead was "Built-in Display" which was highlighted red. I went to check my video drivers (my VGA is Mobility Radeon HD 5650/5750) and found that all the options for video drivers have been greyed out (unclickable) and that the only option in use is "Continue using a manually installed driver". I have no idea what caused this or how to remedy it since I can't find any inquiries with the same problem.

Comment: You could try installing the proper drivers from AMD's site: http://support.amd.com/en-us/download